# Can't change font, i3

Tags: fonts, arch-linux, i3-window-manager, i3

I'm using i3 on ArchCraft. I previously successfully set my font to Terminus, now I want to change it to Google Sans. I tried:
set font option in i3 config to "font pango:IBM Plex Mono Italic 10", "font pango:Google Sans Regular", etc.
Although it doesn't change font at all, it works fine in Firefox and Polybar (if set in theirs configs of course).
Output of **fc-list | grep -i Google**:

```
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-Italic.ttf: Google Sans:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-Medium.ttf: Google Sans,Google Sans Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-Regular.ttf: Google Sans:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-MediumItalic.ttf: Google Sans,Google Sans Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/archcraft/icon-fonts/google-mdi.ttf: google\-mdi:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-BoldItalic.ttf: Google Sans:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/misc/GoogleSans-Bold.ttf: Google Sans:style=Bold
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just needed to change it in `lxappearance`.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please note, SE sites aren't discussion forums. Issues aren't marked resolved by adding "Solved" in the title. Instead the OP accepts the answer that helps resolve the issue, or gets them closest. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) (at least) to learn how these sites work. There's advice on [how to write a question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) or [an answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in a way that helps also others experiencing issues.